# GitHub - how do I push?

Tags: github

Whenever I try to push, GitHub hangs for a while (~a minute) before outputting:

ssh: connect to host gmail.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I checked my SSH keys a few times. I was able to ssh github.com and when I do it asks me for my passphrase and then says, "Hi Aro! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. 
Connection to github.com closed"

First of all, why is it trying to gmail.com when I am using git push? Why is it timing out if the ssh keys seem to be working? I don't see any firewall alerts. I don't think my router is blocking anything. I'm on Windows 7.

What do you think is the problem?

.git/config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = my@email.com:MyGithubUsername/Hello.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: It sounds like a config problem with git, not an SSH connection problem (so not the router, I don't think). Please post your `.git/config` . Seems like it could be using your email address as the server to push to.

Comment: There's your problem. `url` under `[remote "origin"]` should be of the form `git@github.com:MyGithubUsername/Hello.git`.

The authentication is purely done on the basis of keys. No need for usernames or email addresses in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Under `[remote "origin"]`, the `url` value should be changed:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:MyGithubUsername/Hello.git
```

The authentication is purely done on the basis of keys, not the username or email address.